# Spring/Hibernate: Bidirectional Mapping without synchronization for JPQL queries only

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, entity, jpql

In a bidirectional mapping between entities (e.g. `@ManyToOne` ↔ `@OneToMany`), the counterpart needs to be [synchronized on every change](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate), especially when using a 2<sup>nd</sup> level cache. This is usually done with helper methods. Those helper methods do not perform well if the `Many` part contains a lot of entries, because the whole set is fetched each time. A simple example would be an entity `Store` which has `n` `Products`, whereas `n` is very large. Adding a new `Product` to the `Store` would require the `Store` to fetch the whole list of `Products` to finally add it to the set (see code example below).

One could argue, that when modelling such a relation it would be better represented with an unidirectional association from the `Product` to the `Store`. We are using many JPQL queries in our application though. In JPQL, it comes very handy to join entities from both sides.

Do you see any problems when mapping the `@OneToMany` relation in the `Store` entity, when `Many` actually means many and not just a few, and just make the field private, without getters and setters, provided that the whole relation is lazily fetched? As I understand, Hibernate just needs the field to map the relation. And if the set is private, no performance issues should occur?

---

The `Product` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Product {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Store store;

  // setter, getter, helper methods
}
```

The `Store` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Store {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "products", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
  private Set<Product> products;

  // setter, getter, helper methods
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong with it, it's a technique I've used often as well. Of course just make sure that the field is not accessed reflectively in some context (like automatic `toString` builders and similar utilities you may be using).

Also, you don't need the `@Cache` annotation on it since you will never access the collection anyway, thus it will never be cached.